# Error unzipping a file with javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, unzip, filechooser

I am trying to unzip files and it was recommended to me that I use codeJava.net's unzip utility however I cannot get it to work. The following is a snippet of my code that occurs when a button is pressed.

```
  public void fileSelector(Stage primaryStage) {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(new ExtensionFilter("ZIP FILES ONLY", "*.zip"));
    File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);

    if (selectedFile != null) {
      System.out.println(selectedFile);
      UnzipUtility unzipper = new UnzipUtility();
      String destination = System.getProperty("user.dir");
      String finalDestination = destination + "\\books";
      System.out.println(finalDestination);
      String initialDestination = selectedFile.getPath();
      System.out.println(initialDestination);

      try {
        System.out.println("unzipping ... beep boop beep");
        unzipper.unzip(initialDestination, destination);
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

It's meant to use the JavaFX file chooser to choose the file then turn the file path into strings before being used by the unzipper object. You can find the Unzip utility at http://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/programmatically-extract-a-zip-file-using-java.
This is the error I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\EbookReader\books\New folder\1.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `FileNotFoundException: F:\EbookReader\New folder\1.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)` Have you checked if that file actually exists in that path?

Comment: thx for the fast reply ;p. the EBookReader\books folder exists but "New folder/1.txt was what is inside the initial destination. The unzip utility is (im pretty sure) meant to be extracting those files.

Comment: You need to use the whole stack trace. I am guessing that 1.txt is in your zip file and it cannot write the file. Does 'New folder' exist?

Comment: in the ZIP folder is new folder\1.txt. Yeah I think the problem is that it can't write the new files.

Comment: Remove any directories in your zip file and try again. Also, try to debug the `unzip` method and see what exactly happens. Checking permissions in the directory is also an option.

Comment: WOW Thx. It works... I will need folders but hey one stop at a time. Cheers. Plz respond if you have any ideas on how to do that as well.

Comment: You also have the solution to use the zip filesystem provider since you use Java 7+.

Comment: @JamesAdina you will need to create folders if they do not exist.

Comment: Now I have another question that leads from this one, if I have a ZIP folder with one folder inside it but I don't know the name of the folder how do I tell the program to use it? ie... the folder is extracted to /books but if there is multiple folders in /books how do I find the one I just extracted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically the unzipUtility I was using had a fatal error... it couldn't unzip folders. So I did a quick google search and found: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-decompress-files-from-a-zip-file/ 
Its not only works but its also easier to understand which is especially useful to a noob like me. Thx for all of you who commented, it really helped to steer me in the right direction :)